# Can opcua client trigger events to server in Python?

Tags: python, events, opc-ua, opc

i have an issue with the design of my server-client opcua framework.

The thing is, from client i want to send a event notification to opcuaServer. Is this possible?

Until now i can send event triggers from server, but i dont know if client is capable of that.

What gives?

An explanation of code related to the question or a simple answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Think about the problem differently. Maybe the solution is for your client to call a Method on the server, or to write a Value to a specific VariableNode that the server will react to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. At the end i use what u suggests, that is changing a variableNode and having a subscription on Server with DataChange notification. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view you should use the method call. Creating a variable and internally subscribing to it is more of a work around.